# How can I overrule this CSS rule that applies to everything?

Tags: css

I picked up some very handy code that which came with CSS definitions. The problem now is that one rule overrules whatever I define for a Grid on that same page. The result of that rule is very strange: I have to click twice in the TextBox to enter text, I can't select anything from that textbox, hitting 'return' would close the Gridview.

That is the code (with the comment of the guy who wrote that stuff):

```
/* Applies to all. But is overwritten by other style definition for the frozen columns*/
th {
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
background-color:darkseagreen;
color: white;
border-right: 1px solid silver;
position:relative;
cursor: default;
top: expression(document.getElementById("div-datagrid").scrollTop);
z-index: 10;
}
```

Now, the critical line is the top: rule. As long as I do not delete that line, my Grid can't overrule whatever I try to define for my Grid.

Here goes my mark-up for asp.net: (in the style "altGrid" I set top: 0px, but until I do not delete the top: line in the th- definition it doesn't work!)

```
<asp:GridView id="GridView_ActivityDetails" runat="server" CssClass="altGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
    <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Activity" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTBX_Activity" runat="server" Text = '<%# Bind("Activity") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:templatefield>
</Columns>
```

Comment: That CSS doesn't apply to _"everything"_, it applies only to table headers (`th`) so, without knowing what your HTML page structure looks like it will be very hard to come up with any useful advice. See [mcve] in the SO Help Center

Comment: It applies at least without wanting it to the td cell where I'm trying to apply "my" CSS settings. I'll add the markup...

Comment: have you already tried to use `!important`? E.g. `top: 0px !important;` in altGrid?

Comment: Good suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't change anything with the top: 0px !important;